# Is there a Warmoger penalty for capturing Free Cities?

Tags: civilization-6, civilization-6-rise-and-fall

I haven't noticed a penalty for capturing Free Cities so far in Rise and Fall.

Even when an opposing Civ had it's final city declare independance and then I captured that city, I didn't experience the expected drop in diplomatic relations for wiping out a Civ.

Has anyone found evidence that this is indeed the case? I couldn't see anything about it in the Civilopedia.

Comment: As the free cities start off at war with everyone, without the possibility of direct diplomacy or peace with them, I'd say it'd be pretty unfair to up warmonger score for that. You'd essentially be getting a warmonger penalty for e.g. re-establishing your presence in _your own_ city that you lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested this a few more times, and from what I can see there is no Warmonger penalty for caputuring a Free City, even if that Free City used to be the last remaining city of an enemy Civilization.

As has been mentioned, this is likely to prevent you suffering a warmonger penalty for taking your own rebellious cities back by force, but it does provide an amusing (if situational) way to wipe out an AI civ without suffering the "captured a Civ's last city" warmonger bonus.